# Consuming ax2012 services in windows console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, nettcpbinding, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a remote machine with AX2012 installed and in it I have built a custom service in AX2012 and I am able to use it properly in a windows console application (VS2010). But when I try to connect to the service from my own machine through a windows console application (VS2012) , it gives me the error "The server has rejected the client credentials."

My code is as follows :

```
 ServiceReference1.TestService1Client t = new ServiceReference1.TestService1Client();
        t.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "vanya";
        t.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "*******";
        t.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        ServiceReference1.CallContext c = new ServiceReference1.CallContext();
        c.Company = "ussi";
        ServiceReference1.EventList eventss = t.getEventItems(c, "BradPSUS", "contoso.com");
```

The binding in my app.config is as follows :

```
 <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="NetTcpBinding_TestService1" transferMode="Buffered" />

            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ItemService" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

If I add security mode = "none" in the app.config I get the following error "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9609696'"

This same thing works perfectly on the remote machine but does not work on my machine. How do I proceed?

Comment: Is the remote machine running on an internal network? Is this network the same as local machine's? I have no experience of AX 2012, but given the error message you get when you set the security mode to none, and the fact it works remotely, it could be a mismatched subnet.

Comment: The remote machine is on a different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week I have found the solution. Adding the answer to help others who might face this problem in future :

1. Change the adapter of the service from Net.Tcp to HTTP
2. Change security details of service's binding by going to AX->Inbound Port->Configure. 
   [image]
3. Host the service in IIS, you have to host a service on IIS if you want to use it from other domains. This link explains the process http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731848.aspx
4. Enable only windows authentication on IIS.
   [image]
5. Create a console application in visual studio on the same machine on which AX is installed. Add reference to the service. Your app.config should look like this :

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
       <configuration>
        <system.serviceModel>     
         <bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" allowCookies="true"
         maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">

       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
           maxArrayLength="200000000" />
       <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
         <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
       </security>
     </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
       </bindings>
              <client>          
          <endpoint address="http://******/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/Test3/xppservice.svc"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service1"
         contract="ServiceReference1.Service1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" >           
     </endpoint>
   </client>
     </system.serviceModel>
       </configuration>
   ```
6. Take the dll of this console application and paste it in your other machine (the one not on the same domain)
7. Create a console application and add reference to this dll. Use this dll to access the service.
8. Paste the same app.config contents.
9. Add these three lines in the .cs file

   ```
       workListSvc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "*****";
       workListSvc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "kevin";
       workListSvc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "*****";
   ```
10. Should work now.